# Return pages based on user role in nextjs 14.0.4 (app router)

Tags: express, authentication, next.js, authorization

I am new to Nextjs, so I am not familiar how should I organize my files and the right methods to have separate view for each user role, I have 2 roles "admin" and "user" each role should have a separate dashboard and a separate view in the frontend. I am using nextjs 14.0.4 with the app router just as a frontend, and I have an external API built with express to handle user authentication and backend functionality.

My external API sends a JWT token in a cookie after login which contains the user role.

I would like to know what is a good practice to handle authentication using my external API, then receive the jwt token in nextjs after login, then ask the API about my role based on jwt token and then render the appropriate section of the frontend based on user role.

I created a server side login page in nextjs and on submit I am calling a server action which calls the login endpoint at my API with a fetch request, then I get the cookie from the response headers and set it in the browser, I created a function called getUserInfo that takes the cookie from the browser and make a request to the API to check user role, and then make if condition in any nextjs component to check on role before rendering.

I think this method is not scalable and messy that is why I am asking for recommendations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.